# Got an exception! You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: java, mysql

I got this error i am using java and javafx and it is connected to MYsql DB i got this error while excute this statment from java to my sql please help

Got an exception!

> ```
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'update kstds.match SET
> kstds.match.Team1Goals=kstds.match.Team1Goals+1 where kst' at line 1
> ```

[image]

```
String Query ="use kstds; update kstds.match SET kstds.match.Team1Goals=kstds.match.Team1Goals+1 "
            + "where kstds.match.Team1ID= ( select kstds.team.TeamID from kstds.team  where kstds.team.Name='AHLI' ) "
            + "and kstds.match.Matchid = 1 ; "
            + "Update kstds.match SET kstds.match.Team2Goals=kstds.match.Team2Goals+1 "
            + "where kstds.match.Team2ID= ( select kstds.team.TeamID from kstds.team where kstds.team.Name='AHLI' ) "
            + "and kstds.match.Matchid=1;";
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your query?

Comment: Q: So what happens if you make your query a single statement (remove the "use kstds").

Comment: quote the team name "AHLI". Execute a single query at a time. So not 2 or more update queries. Default database `kstds` is part of the connection.

Comment: in mysql it works but in java it wont!. i tried to (remove the "use kstds) no diffrence. i want to check two conditions if one of them matched i want to excuted as i said in mysql it works proporly + i used at the begin 'AHLI' the qoutes also it does not work. i am confuised beecause same statments works in mysql very good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to execute multiple sql queries which should be done using  `addBatch` & `executeBatch`.
you don't have to execute `use kstds` because the connection to the database is set via Java

try this:

```
String Query1 ="update match SET match.Team1Goals=match.Team1Goals+1 "
            + "where match.Team1ID= ( select team.TeamID from team  where team.Name='AHLI' ) "
            + "and match.Matchid = 1 ; "
String Query2 ="Update match SET match.Team2Goals=match.Team2Goals+1 "
            + "where match.Team2ID= ( select team.TeamID from team where team.Name='AHLI' ) "
            + "and match.Matchid=1;";
//stmt is your Statement and conn is your Connection  
con.setAutoCommit(false);        
stmt.addBatch(Query1); 
stmt.addBatch(Query2);
stmt.executeBatch();
con.commit();
```